# React-Tab id tag not working how do I getElementByID?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app, there is a tab list:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <Tabs>
          <TabList>
            <Tab id="abc">ABC</Tab>
            <Tab>DEF</Tab>
          </TabList>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In the console getElementById("abc") returns null. Why?

Proper way to get an element in React JS code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to do `document.getElementById("abc")` (note lowercase d)

Comment: I just type it from memory.